# Show that there does not exist natural number $x$, $y$ s.t. $x^2 -y^2 =1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

Assume $∃xy∈N$ st. $x^2-y^2 =1$

$(x-y)(x+y) = 1$ so;

$(x-y)∈N$ and $(x+y)∈N$

How do I proceed from the information I know

Comment: I guess you are assuming that $0$ is not a natural number (otherwise $1^2-0^2=1$), but that is not a widespread convention.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have:

$(x-y)(x+y) = 1$

and

$(x-y)∈N$ and $(x+y)∈N$

Well, the only way for the product of two natural numbers to be $1$ is for both numbers to be $1$.

So: $x-y=1$ and $x+y=1$

You can take it from there ...

(p.s. $x=1$ and $y=0$ would be a solution, so I assume you don't include $0$ as part of your natural numbers)

Answer (score 2):

If $y^2$ is a square ($y\in\Bbb N)$, the next square up is $(y+1)^2=y^2+1+2y$ which is more than $y^2+1$....

Answer (score 1):

$(y+1)^2-y^2=2y+1 $ since $x,y$ are natural the smallest value of $y$ is $1$ for which the sequence $2y+1$ have a value of $3$ and for other values it keeps on increasing.